# express.js routes explanation

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, express

I was looking at [express.js](/questions/tagged/express.js) source code, to find out how it maps named route parameters to `req.params` properties.

For those who don't know, in **express.js** you can define routes with named parameters, make them optional, only allow the ones with specific format (and more):

```
app.get("/user/:id/:name?/:age(\\d+)", function (req, res) {
    console.log("ID is", req.params.id);
    console.log("Name is", req.params.name || "not specified!");
    console.log("Age is", req.params.age);
});
```

I realized that the heart of this functionality is a method called [`pathRegexp()`](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/lib/utils.js#L260) defined in [lib/utils.js](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/lib/utils.js). The method definition is as follows:

```
function pathRegexp(path, keys, sensitive, strict) {
    if (path instanceof RegExp) return path;
    if (Array.isArray(path)) path = '(' + path.join('|') + ')';
    path = path
        .concat(strict ? '' : '/?')
        .replace(/\/\(/g, '(?:/')
        .replace(/(\/)?(\.)?:(\w+)(?:(\(.*?\)))?(\?)?(\*)?/g, function (_, slash, format, key, capture, optional, star) {
            keys.push({ name: key, optional: !! optional });
            slash = slash || '';
            return ''
                + (optional ? '' : slash)
                + '(?:'
                + (optional ? slash : '')
                + (format || '') + (capture || (format && '([^/.]+?)' || '([^/]+?)')) + ')'
                + (optional || '')
                + (star ? '(/*)?' : '');
        })
        .replace(/([\/.])/g, '\\$1')
        .replace(/\*/g, '(.*)');
    return new RegExp('^' + path + '$', sensitive ? '' : 'i');
}
```

The important part is the regex on line 7, `/(\/)?(\.)?:(\w+)(?:(\(.*?\)))?(\?)?(\*)?/g` which groups the matched portions of pathname this way:

<kbd>slash</kbd>    
<kbd>the `/` symbol</kbd>

<kbd>format</kbd>  
<kbd>I don't know what is the purpose of this one, explanation needed.</kbd>

<kbd>key</kbd>      
<kbd>the word (ie. `\w+`) after the `:` symbol</kbd>

<kbd>capture</kbd>
<kbd>a regex written in front of the `key`. Should be wrapped in parenthesis (ex. `(.\\d+)`)</kbd>

<kbd>optional</kbd>
<kbd>the `?` symbol after the `key`</kbd>

<kbd>star</kbd>      
<kbd>the `*` symbol</kbd>

and the callback handler builds a regex from the groups above.

---

**Now the question is**, what is the purpose of `format` here?

My understanding according to the following line:

```
(format || '') + (capture || (format && '([^/.]+?)' || '([^/]+?)'))
```

and the mentioned regex is,

if you put a `.` symbol after the `slash` group and don't specify a match condition (the regex wrapped in parenthesis after the `key`), the generated regex matches the rest of `path` until it gets to a `.` or `/` symbol.

So what's the point?

---

I'm asking this, because:

1. I want to extract and use this method in my app and want to fully understand how it works before using it.
2. I didn't find anything on **express.js** documentation about it.
3. I'm just curious :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is for matching file extensions and such properly.

Given the path `'/path/:file.:ext'`, consider the difference between the expressions:

```
// With 'format' checking
/^\/path\/(?:([^\/]+?))(?:\.([^\/\.]+?))\/?$/

// Without 'format' checking
/^\/path\/(?:([^\/]+?))(?:([^\/]+?))\/?$/
```

In the first case, you end up with params as

```
{
    file: 'file',
    ext: 'js'
}
```

but without the format checking, you end up with this:

```
{
    file: 'f',
    ext: 'ile.js'
}
```