# Ignoring words in an express route

Tags: regex, node.js, express, routes

I have the following routes:

```
app.get('/blah/query.json', doSomething);
app.get('/blah/:id.:format', doSomethingElse);
```

Currently both routes continue on so route one (query.json) is called and then route two is called (:id.:format).  How can I exclude a call to route two if route one is called.  I tried something like this:

```
app.get('/blah^\/(?!query)(:id.:format)$', doSomethingElse);
```

But this, and several variations of this, didn't seem to work.  I found a post that references the express code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15316110/express-js-routes-explanation).  Even looking at this code and trying different things I am still  having trouble getting the "If not query" expression to work.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you calling `next` inside `doSomething`?

Comment: Yes, neither method returns a response to the requestor, instead they do things and call next

Comment: Why don't they send a response? It seems like you are really fighting the intended usage of Express. Calling `next` is explicitly saying to execute the next handler, and that is what you are trying to avoid. In my mind, really the only time you should call `next` in a route callback is to pass an error. Happy to try to suggest alternatives if you post more info about your routing.

Comment: The problem is in a framework I'm creating.  I have simplified the problem for posting on stack.  I understand the common use, however since using regular expressions in a route would be an ideal solution it would be great to know if you can combine regular expressions with express request parameters.

Answer (score 0):

What if you set a semaphore like the following?:

```
var sempahore_execute_second = true;

app.get('/blah/query.json', function(req,res,next){
    sempahore_execute_second = false;
});

app.get('/blah/:id.:format', function(req,res,next){
    if (sempahore_execute_second) {
        // Execute code here.
    };
}));

// or better:
app.get('/blah/:id.:format', function(req,res,next){
    if (sempahore_execute_second) return next();

    // Execute code here.
}));
```

I know is a bit messy and you should look forward another solution, but maybe this can help you at the moment.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am currently using something similar using res.locals in express to mark a request as "handled" as a hot fix.  However in this question I am trying to find a way to avoid executing the second route all together using regular expressions.